# Is there a way to track how much time you use with each application on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I'd like to see how much time I spend each day with each application on Windows 11.

And also, if possible, each website within Google Chrome on Windows 11.

Also posted at [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_11-wintop_apps-win_subtopwinapps/is-there-a-way-to-track-how-much-time-you-use-with/bd43e545-72e2-4ab4-8992-5bbcf135d3d5?messageId=78d28364-4de5-42e6-9c1b-e5b4c97cf14b&tm=1694166079865)

Comment: It would seem likely someone's developed software for this, but if not, one tedious way to do so would be via Task Scheduler [`taskschd.msc`], using events from Event Viewer [`eventvwr.msc`] as triggers

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HT Work Focus](https://ht-vector.com/ht-work-focus) does a good job.

It tracks application time, website time & more, and allows you to set blocks & limits on websites & applications.

Answer (score 1):

There may exist third-party applications, but Windows itself
can track app activity if you have signed-in using a
Microsoft Account and have enabled Activity history
in *Settings > Privacy*.

It helps keep track of the things you do on your device, such
as the apps and services you use, the files you open, and the
websites you browse.

Your activity history is stored locally on your device, and if
you are signed-in with a Microsoft account and given your permission, Windows sends your activity history to Microsoft. Microsoft uses
this activity history data to provide you with personalized experiences
(such as ordering your activities based on duration of use)
and relevant suggestions (such as anticipating what your needs
might be based on your activity history).

See this article for more information:
[Windows activity history and your privacy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/-windows-activity-history-and-your-privacy-2b279964-44ec-8c2f-e0c2-6779b07d2cbd).

Comment: Note: I've never used Activity history and cannot know first-hand how good it is.